# Create row space (betw. content, not text-line space) in HTML or CSS

Tags: html, css, r

I have an R Markdown doc in R, where I instead of having a header with "Preface", I just want to indicate this with these grey lines.

[image]

I've created a CSS-id in the .rmd-file in which I have just this code:

```
:::{#preface}
<p>
Text
</p>
:::
```

But as can be seen there's 0 row margin in the beginning and some and the end?
Adding a `<br>`  in the begging is to much, I want something as the likes of: [A document with good row space in the beg. and end](https://www.riksbank.se/globalassets/media/rapporter/ppr/fordjupningar/svenska/2018/phillipskurvan-och-penningpolitiken-fordjupning-i-penningpolitisk-rapport-juli-2018.pdf)

I can't use padding(?) since in my css i add the border there, and padding would affect the distance between the 'box' and borders ye(?):

```
#preface{
  border-top:1px solid #a19c97;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #a19c97;
}
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Thinking about it, maybe a bad solution is to add 2 more CSS-id, one before *#preface* and one after and put the border in those and use padding in the preface-id. I could try that if there's no better solution.

Comment: `margin` (instead of `padding`) might be what you're looking for

Comment: Jag skulle kunna köra ```margin```  på ```<p>```  men då ändrar jag ju globalt för alla classer som använder "p" - finns det ett sätt att bara ändra margin på "p" classen i id: preface?

Comment: You could by defining a CSS *class* "preface" (`.preface = {...}`) and applying it like `<p class = "preface">...</p>`. Still that shouldn't be necessary because in your example you target the HTML elements by ID, not by node type (`<p>` ) anyway.

Comment: Actually the padding worked - I don't seem to understand how ```border-top``` works, because I was totally sure it wouldn't.

Comment: If "*the padding worked*" would you mind writing an answer to your question, explaining and showing what you did? This may help future visitors to the site, as well as serving as aide-memoire for you, too.

Comment: Sure I'll do that, but it worked as you normally think - but it padded from the border-top and not from the box of the #preface - the latter which I thought it would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `border-top` creates a border at the top and the use of `padding` is from that specific element.

When writhing this question I was quite sure that padding would also affect `border-top` **which it does not seem to do.**

The `border-top` is right in between green and orange box (in pic).

[image]

My CSS for this `#preface` is:

```
#preface{
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-top:1px solid #95c11f;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #95c11f;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```